# How to set default color and brightness of LEDs of the DualShock 4 controller on Linux?

Tags: controllers, linux

I've bought a DualShock 4 controller and don't own a PlayStation 4 console. It's recognized on my ArchLinux systems out of the box. Newer kernels support it natively.

The sole issue is that by default, once it's connected to Bluetooth, it sets its LED to blue on full brightness. Besides the light being too strong, it reduces controller's battery time a lot.

Is there a way to configure a default brightness and/or color without additional and/or alternative drivers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've created a udev rule for this that works just fine. First it's needed to identify device attributes once the controller is connected, e.g.:

```
udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/input/js0)
```

This will print a bunch of useful information that can be used to create a udev rule to match the device once it's connected, and execute something.

Here, I've picked `ATTRS{uniq}` to indentify my controller in specific (one can also use a more general DualShock 4 match, picking `ATTRS{name}=="Wireless Controller"` for example):

`/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules`

```
# Set First DualShock 4 LED color

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{uniq}=="dc:0c:2d:d3:a7:0c" RUN+="/usr/local/bin/ds4led '%p' 000100"
```

It's possible to control LED brightness and color by writing RGB values to paths similar to the following:

```
echo 255 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/0005:054C:09CC.000B:blue/brightness
```

The above sets my controller's blue component to maximum brightness. The `0005:054C:09CC.000B` part of the path may vary per connection.

The previous udev rule executes the following script, which accepts two arguments, a path that contains a pattern like `0005:054C:09CC.000B`, which it extracts to build the `/sys/class/leds/0005:054C:09CC.000B:blue/brightness` path, and a color in the RRGGBB form:

`/usr/local/bin/ds4led` (do not forget to set executable permission for this)

```
#!/bin/bash

RED=$((16#${2:0:2}))
GREEN=$((16#${2:2:2}))
BLUE=$((16#${2:4:2}))

LED=$(echo "$1" | egrep -o '[[:xdigit:]]{4}:[[:xdigit:]]{4}:[[:xdigit:]]{4}\.[[:xdigit:]]{4}')

[[ -z "$LED" || ! -d "/sys/class/leds/$LED:global" ]] && exit

echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/$LED:red/brightness
echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/$LED:green/brightness
echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/$LED:blue/brightness

echo $RED > /sys/class/leds/$LED:red/brightness
echo $GREEN > /sys/class/leds/$LED:green/brightness
echo $BLUE > /sys/class/leds/$LED:blue/brightness
```

`ds4led` can both be called manually like `sudo ds4led /sys/class/leds/0005:054C:09CC.000B:global 0000FF` or from a udev rule by passing `%p` as the first argument. Even though udev will pass a `devpath` that's completely different from `/sys/class/leds/...`, it'll still contain a pattern like `0005:054C:09CC.000B` in it.

Comment: **This is amazing.** You know it. This would be even *more* amazing housed in a Git{Hub,Lab} repository, though. I'd love to see what the open-source community could spin out from this humble beginning. Light cycling, for example – could we make that happen as well, perhaps as a low-priority background daemon process?

Answer (score 1):

Here's where Linux's hid-sony driver defines the default LED colors if you feel like fixing this at the source level:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1e2a199f6ccdc15cf111d68d212e2fd4ce65682e/drivers/hid/hid-sony.c#L1944

Comment: This answer could be more future-proofed by linking to the file and stating the function name within the file.  Currently, line 1825 of hid-sony.c is part of the gyroscope calibration code rather than the LED controller code (presumably since more code was added to that file since you made this post).  I presume that you were referring to dualshock4_set_leds_from_id() in your answer (which is now on line 1944 as of this comment).

Comment: Thanks, I switched to a permalink

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ds4drv` supports changing the controller's color, although not when connected over bluetooth and `hidraw` (which unfortunately is the only way mine connects). Worth a shot though: https://github.com/chrippa/ds4drv#command-line-options

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OpenRGB](https://openrgb.org/).
It works with my ds4 controller using a wired connection or bluetooth.

And if you have other rgb devices it can probably control them as well.